# Is there any stty option that puts the terminal in raw mode but still lets it generate a signal for e.g. CTRL+Z

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal, stty

There are many options for `stty`. What I want is based on `stty raw -echo`: I'm wondering if I can add an option that makes the terminal driver  send a signal when it sees e.g. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>, instead of having my program handle this keypress.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `raw` option for `stty` is shorthand for `-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl -ixon -ixoff -icanon -opost -isig -iuclc -ixany -imax‐ bel -xcase min 1 time 0`

The `-isig` in this list prevents the terminal from responding to e.g. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>

Adding `isig` *after* `raw` (like in `stty raw -echo isig`) will cancel the `-isig` that is implicit in `raw`, and give you a terminal in raw mode that still responds to  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> (any of the characters  `INTR`, `QUIT`, `SUSP`, or `DSUSP`, in fact)